# I want to run a batch file without start up and without task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file

well to put it in simple terms, I have a batch file ready to run on log-on. I tried to put it into the system files to keep it present when changing users (I do not have admin controls which is why I'm using this method) then when any user logs on, I want it to run the file. now here's where the problem occurs I can't use task schedular because without admin controls I would only be editing it to set off for my account only which is not what I want, the next option I tried was to imbed the file in startup so it would activate on a new logon but surprise surprise the file only belongs in **my user files only** so when they log on the file is gone. so how can I run the file automatically and keep it in system files at the same time to keep it from being removed via log-on?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do what you want. Get someone who is Admin to make a startup Task that you can run. Or, put the script in the Group Policy location with GPEdit,msc. The later works really well for simple startup scripts.

Comment: Group Policy also needs admin use to be edited let alone my knowledge on this particular application is very minimal anyway

Comment: Yes I know that. That is why I said get the organization with Admin credentials to do this for you.

Comment: As others state, you can't get a task to run for *another user* unless you have higher administrative rights, e.g., Administrator, or when Windows installs as TrustedUser.

Comment: What you want is what any hacker would like to have. Windows will do everything it can to block it.

Comment: im not trying to hack anything but some guy a period before me in school messes up my keyboard settings and changes my mouse speed to 1 pixel per second. so I'm trying to get back at him by haveing a file pop open and harmlessly rick roll him constantly every minute to get back at whoevers before me.

Comment: though if i cant do this id would not mind revenge in a different way if you have any thoughts

Comment: sorry, you will find this community has no sense of humor that we are aware of, and as such, we don't see a distinction between pranks and malicious hacking.  As a general rule, a non-admin user can only impact their own user experience. it does appear that your adversary has discovered a rare user-mode global setting (the mouse speed (which I'll admit, I'm surprised that that is not user-specific),  but you will have to restrict yourself to tricks similar to the one they used.  you will not be able to run arbitrary scripts within their session unless you can gain system-level access somehow.

Comment: yea didn't think this community was for this kind of thing which is why I tried to be serious as possible without saying reason as I sensed the "no humor vibe" the second one of my comments was shut down for making a simple remark against a common thing I wasn't aware of in the c++ language. but regardless the only reason why i chose this platform is BECAUSE people are serious (and have helpful answers too) but if this is too much for this platform ill move it to Reddit and see what they say. thanks for trying though. but I will say I am not doing this out of malicious intent whatsoever.